# Apply function.php filter only if url not has /amp/

Tags: php, functions, filters, paths

I applied a filter to remove theme styles and javascript in function.php, but I want this to happen only if the url not ends with /amp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `amp`? Is it tag or category or page? You should use standard wordpress functions like `is_page()` `is_category()` `is_tag()`.
You can also use `$wp->request`. It will return the request URI. If the address is `"http://example.com/slug1/slug2"` it will return `slug1/slug2` then use `explode()` function to split it.

```
<?php  $uri =  $wp->request; 
$slugs = explode("/",$uri);//variable $slugs will have array of slugs 

//$slugs[count($slugs)-1] will return last slug
if($slugs[count($slugs)-1] != "amp") {
//Apply your filter filter here
}
 ?>
```

Remember $wp is a global variable so if you want to use it inside a function the must use the keyword `global` before it.

Comment: Thanks for helping, i will use this code inside function.php, my code in function.php `function disable_scripts_styles() {
 wp_dequeue_style('publisher');
 wp_dequeue_style('better-framework-main-fonts');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_scripts_styles', 100);` and the url is https://sitename.com/article/amp/ so i dont apply this function if the url has amp